# In a 3g/4g private APN network, I can't ping all the address's on the network?

Tags: routing, wireless, wan

I'm tasked to monitor the connectivity -Health- of a Private APN network,
our setup is like this:

We have SIM cards , each has a static IP address, we are using a 4G Gateway at each remote site. Most of the SIM cards are 4G but some are 3G - I came to know this through the Gateway Status window - I want to know why I am not able to ping any 3G sim card ip address from a 4G one , when all the hardware and configuration are identical.

This is one private network , why would the type of connection change anything.  Please if you have the knowledge to explain it or if you can point me to the right direction in troubleshooting the issue don't hesitate , also I'm ready to answer any question.

Comment: Obviously, your provider is crap. The APN on the 3G gear isn't linked with the APN on the 4G gear. This could be a simple oversight. Talk to your provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that the network suppose to be 3G in the contract and that the main router at the costumer HQ site is 3G only , now i need to statically specify the band on each router , however its still a mystery to me why would some SIM cards elevate to 4G while some will lose connectivity if forced to and only work 3G , The gateways them self's by default always prefer 4G , and the ISP Main Service does not mind apparently to route at 4G band between what is suppose to be lower band, and by doing that it creates a separate network.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Private APN sounds like there is no VPN configuration required on your equipment - the provider does that for you.

Is there an internal and separate provider facing IP address on the 3G gateway?  If so, can you ping the inside facing IP address?

It may be that ping to the external facing address simply will not work and you may have to access the device via the internal facing address.

Comment: Please ask questions in comments, not answers.

Comment: Maieutics.  However, I appreciate your concern.  There is value in my answer yet it gets voted down.  Also, you allow particular users to persist in abusive behavior (see comment to OP).  Please give that some attention.

Comment: Ron Royston, yes the Provider ensures the privacy and isolation, no there is no separate provider , and i can't contact the 3G gateway anyway,